# Importing from subfolder in python package fails

Tags: python, packaging

I have a project

```
B/
|---C/
|---|---setup.py [with name=G.H.C]
|---|---G/
|---|---|---H/
|---|---|---|---C/
|---|---|---|---|---__init__.py
|---|---|---|---|---code.py
|---D/
|---|---setup.py [with name=G.H.D]
|---|---G/
|---|---|---H/
|---|---|---|---D/
|---|---|---|---|---__init__.py
|---|---|---|---|---main.py
|---|---|---|---|---samelevelasmain.py
|---|---|---|---|---E/
|---|---|---|---|---|---notsamelevelasmain.py
```

main.py looks like

```
from G.H.C.code import func1 [linter recognises this]
from G.H.D.samelevelasmain import func2 [linter recognises this]
from G.H.D.E.notsamelevelasmain import func3 [linter does not recognise this]
```

I went to directories C and D and ran `pip install .` and verified with `pip list` that they were in my environment. Why does the linter not recognise G.H.D.E?

I tried `__init__.py` in E. No dice. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Python3